# ASP.NET,dropdownlist and response redirect

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, response.redirect

Here is what I am trying to do. select a value from dropdown and move to that page and postback.

1.aspx page

```
<asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>d</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Csfile:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Enabled = true;           
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("disable", "disable");
        if (this.Session["Template"] == "a ")
        {
            this.DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("disable", "disable");
        }
    }

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "a")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/a.aspx");
       DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("disable", "disable");
    }
```

On selecting option ‘a’ redirecting to page a.aspx, after filling the details moves back to page 1.aspx

Here I want to disable the dropdown so user cant reselect from that particular dropdown. I tried all the above options but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are always enabling your dropdown list because on moving back to the page it is no longer a postback. Postback is only when a page post back to itself, not when another page posts to it.

Your code says "if it's a postback do this, otherwise do this" and you're never actually hitting the "otherwise".

Change it so that it's something like:

This is assuming you don't have an `Enabled="false"` on your HTML view for the drop down list. If you don't, then there is no need to set `Enabled=true;` as it's `true` by default.

```
if (!IsPostBack)    
    {    

              if (this.Session["Template"] == "a ")    
               {    
                  DropDownList1.Enabled = false;    
               }           

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Much for the answer. But still dint get it to work. my cs file now is protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{     

    if (!IsPostBack)

    { if(this.session["Template"] == "a"){

        DropDownList1.Enabled = false;           
}
    }

Comment: check that you actually have `"a"` in `Session["Template"]` - validate it in debugger - don't just assume it's set :)